# What does the output mean when I print a tensor in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Sorry if this is obvious. But as the title says, what does it mean when I print a tensor in the console.

```
print(tf.constant([1,2]))
# Tensor("Const_7:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
```

I understand the `shape` and `dtype`, but how about `Const_7:0`? `Const` looks to me is the `operation` that creates the tensor. What is `:0` then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Const_7 means the name of this operation and name of an operation should be unique in a single graph. Port 0 means the first output tensor of this op. Some operation has many output tensors like tf.split and these tensors are named with the a port after the name of this operation.